# Pod installs under Windows Helm instead of Linux

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, gitlab

I am trying to activate Helm Tiller to talk to our Azure Kubernetes Cluster.

The cluster has two nodes.

The default Linux node. And we added a windows node. Which is what we are going to use.

Here is our issue.

When I add an existing Kubernetes Cluster via the Gitlab Portal.

It seems to link. Then it tells me to click a button to install Helm Tiller.

I can get the Tiller server to install on the Linux node.

But for some reason.

Under the gitlab-managed-apps namespace it tries to install a pod called install-Helm under the windows node instead of the Linux node.

How can I tell Gitlab to install this pod under our Linux node instead of our windows node?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

After adding cluster to Gitlab, dont immediately initiate HELM Tiller installation. You have to prepare nodes first of all.

The tools we will use are

```
kubectl drain
```

> Drain node in preparation for maintenance.
>
> The given node will be marked unschedulable to prevent new pods from
>   arriving. 'drain' evicts the pods if the APIServer
>   supportshttp://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/disruptions/ . Otherwise, it
>   will use normal DELETE to delete the pods. The 'drain' evicts or
>   deletes all pods except mirror pods (which cannot be deleted through
>   the API server).  If there are DaemonSet-managed pods, drain will not
>   proceed without --ignore-daemonsets, and regardless it will not delete
>   any DaemonSet-managed pods, because those pods would be immediately
>   replaced by the DaemonSet controller, which ignores unschedulable
>   markings.  If there are any pods that are neither mirror pods nor
>   managed by ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, DaemonSet, StatefulSet
>   or Job, then drain will not delete any pods unless you use --force. 
>   --force will also allow deletion to proceed if the managing resource of one or more pods is missing.
>
> 'drain' waits for graceful termination. You should not operate on the
>   machine until the command completes.
>
> When you are ready to put the node back into service, use kubectl
>   uncordon, which will make the node schedulable again.

```
kubectl uncordon
```

> Mark node as schedulable.

So what you need to do is drain windows node in order to make it Unschedulable during tiller installation:

```
kubectl drain <your-windows-node> --force

kubectl describe node  <your-windows-node> should show you:
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      true
```

Next is go to Gitlab and install Tiller: it will be installed on your 2nd(linux node).

You can verify that tiller was installed on correct node by

```
kubectl get pods -o wide -n gitlab-managed-apps
```

After Tiller installation is completed - simply uncordon windows node - that will again allow kubernetes schedule new pods into this node:

```
kubectl uncordon <your-windows-node>
```

You can read more info about drains in [official documentation with an example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/)

Yet another solution is to apply labels for your nodes, eg `os=win; os=linux` and install Tiller manually using [node selectors](https://helm.sh/docs/install/#using-node-selectors).
So you have to:

- apply labels to nodes
- create manually `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace
- create serviceaccount in given namespace
- create clusterrolebindings
- install tiller in needed namespace(version of installed tiller is important. As I know gitlab install not the newest one)
- check if gitlab see this Tiller installation from UI. From my experience - I was able to do that, but I had ssl warnings and came to first solution.

For reference:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get | bash
kubectl create namespace gitlab-managed-apps
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace gitlab-managed-apps tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=gitlab-managed-apps:tiller
helm init --node-selectors "os"="linux"--tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps --service-account tiller
```

Comment: Thanks VKR!

I sent another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246095/handling-ci-with-gitlab-and-azure-kubernetes

if you can help with this. That would be awesome to.