# Handling CI with GitLab and Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, gitlab, azure-aks

Building a docker image using Docker in Docker is not working.

before_script:

```
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
  - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/
  - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl  
  - chmod +x ./kubectl
  - mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:dind
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://127.0.0.1:2376    
  script:
    - kubectl version
    - docker info
```

Getting: `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server`

Comment: Looks like the issue might be in connecting to your GitLab Runner, which I’m assuming is running on your Azure kubernetes instance.

Comment: That is correct. It’s under the Gitlab Managed Apps namespace. Any idea how to fix this?